# Solution for Non-Square Matrix - What Am I Doing Wrong

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm attempting to solve a matrix problem $Ax = b$. since A is of shape (7,4), and b is (7,1), I know I have some work to do first.
I thought I had grasped how to do this, and I do end up with an answer. Sadly, the answer I get is not correct. Here's how I did it:
$$ (A⊤  A)^{-1}  A⊤ b $$
And here's the details of my specific problem:
$$A = [[ 1,   1,  24,   2 ]
     [ 2,   2,  32,   1.3]
     [ 3,   3,  20,   2.2]
     [ 3,   4,  28,   4.4]
     [ 3,   3,  32,   4.4]
     [ 5,   4,  18,   2.4]
     [ 5,   5,  24,   5. ]]$$
$$b = [ 642
     ,1533
     ,926
     ,1135
     ,1066
     ,695
     ,1206] $$
The result I get is:
$$x = [-20.053221469947133, 38.95067294268851, 38.528524047184476, -172.17483493538492]$$
Which, when dotted with any row in A, shows a result which seems to be in the right neighborhood, but is not correct. E.g.,
$$A[0]x = 769.3094219890714 \neq b[0] $$

I'm wondering if this is due to floating point handling, but I also think I may be failing to grasp something here. Can somebody show me the way?